# Please help me find this psychedelic rock (?) song!

Tags: identify-this-song, rock

I've been listening to this mix:
https://www.mixcloud.com/by4konata/metatronshotblast-ep02-weird-progressive/

and the track at 8:40 is absolutely mindblowing! It seems to be some sort of psychedelic rock, but I can't find the lyrics or any indication as to the artist or song name. Help me find it please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SoundHound I quickly found [Cigaretta - Change Coming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2h7HJKT_Yc).

Comment: thanks for ID-ing the track, have a weakness for psychdelic rock